# Redux, React native - memoized selector returning warning related to unneccessary re-renders

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using the  `CreateSelector` function in order to create a memoized selector. **This is the selector in my Chatpage.js**:

```
  const makeSelectMessages= createSelector(
    (state) => state.messages.messages,
    (messagesInfo) => {
      if (!messagesInfo) return emptyArray
      return messagesInfo[id]
    }
  )
```

I call useSelector below the created selector inside **ChatPage.js** like follows:

`const messages = useSelector(makeSelectChatMessages)`

However when **ChatPage.js** loads, I get the error: `WARN  Selector unknown returned a different result when called with the same parameters. This can lead to unnecessary rerenders. Selectors that return a new reference (such as an object or an array) should be memoized:`.

When removing the messages selector, everything returns to normal, so I assume this selector is causing the issue.

This is the reducer function that updates `state.messages.messages`:

```
       const initialState= {
         messagesData: {},
         starredMessages: {}
       }


       setMessages: (state, action) => {
            const existingMessages = state.messagesData
            const {id, messagesData} = action.payload

            existingMessages[id] = messagesData

            
            state.messagesData = existingMessages
        },
```

I use **dispatch** to update the messages state inside **onValue**, which is called everytime there is a change in the firebase database, e.g a new message has been pushed. This is done as follows:

```
        const messagesRef = child(dbRef, `messages/${chatId}`)
        refs.push(messagesRef)

        onValue(messagesRef, (messagesSnapshot) => {
          const messagesData = messagesSnapshot.val()
          // HERE IS WHERE THE UPDATE TO THE STATE OCCURS
          dispatch(setChatMessages({chatId, messagesData}))
        })
```

I would also like to add that the **messages selector does return the correct data, and successfully updates when dispatch is called**, however the warning persists, and causes multiple re-renders, slowing down performance immensly. Any solutions I can implement? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the recommendations from [redux doc](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#createselector-overview) ? 
It looks like you could create a separate "input selector" for your messages and use it as an argument of makeSelectMessages.